# Log data for wrong user login using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

I am using JMeter for performance testing. I have a set of users in a .csv file and am using csv config element.

Even if the login failed, it is showing that the request ran successfully. What is the way to get log data for users with wrong password during testing?

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Edit > Add > Assertions > Response Assertion**
In response assertion you can assert by checking the response code, message and header.
If the assertion doesn't match then request will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add assertion to validate the response, so that if login fails it notifies the request as fail in test results.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) below 400 as successful, it doesn't do any checks against response and knows nothing regarding login request being successful.

You can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) in order to verify whether your user is logged in, i.e.

- Check that text like `Welcome, ${username}` is present
- Check that `Logout` link is present
- Check that message regarding wrong credentials is absent

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more details on conditionally failing JMeter samplers basing on various criteria.

If you're looking for a way to store username/password combinations somewhere so you could tell which ones were "bad" I believe the easiest option is using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property.